# Что такое файлы core на сервере?

Tags: linux, nginx, сервер

Хотел скопировать файл сертификатов с локального компьютера на сервер командой " scp -i путь_до_id_rsa путь_до_файла_моего_сертификата centos@99.99.99.99:/etc/ssl/certs".
Сервер спросил про подтверждение подключения по ssh. Я 2 раза ввел yes и yes и терминал завис - началось что-то типа
"
y
y
y
y
y
"
И так до бесконечности. Я сбросил процесс ctrl+C. В итоге на сервере - куча файлов core. И оказывается они по 20Mb в среднем

Что с этим делать и чем это грозит?(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это файлы (корки) - это дамп после падения процессе. Какого именно - по имени не сказать, виден только его пид на момент падения. Его можно открыть с помощью gdb и посмотреть стек падения, правда нужен ещё и бинарь.

Comment: Да судя по всему вы спилили сук, на котором сидели. `ssh` стало плохо, когда из-под него увели сертификаты.

Comment: @0andriy SSH не использует SSL сертификаты...